# Writing an observable that you can subscribe too and makes an http call once

Tags: angular, observable

I'm coming from an angularjs world and something I was able to do before at first seemed to translate but after inspecting the network I'm getting multiple calls firing.

In the anguylarjs I would of done something like this in a service:

```
function call(){
    if(service.promise){
        return service.promise
    };
    service.promise = http.get(...)
        .then(function(){
            ...
            return ...;
        }, function(){
            ...
        });
    return service.promise;
}
```

To call it would be simple

```
call(); //fires the http call
call(); //does not fire the http call again
```

I tried to replicate it with observables in angular but the http call always fires for each subscribe:

```
call(): Observable<...>{
    if(service.observable){
        return service.observable;
    }

    service.observable = this.httpClient.get<...>(...)
        .flatMap(data => {
            ...
            return of(...);
        });

    return service.observable;
}
```

So if I subscribe too it twice it's always doing the http call

```
call() //fires the http call
    .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
call() //fires the http call again
    .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

I could also be doing an anti-pattern here.

Comment: Use the shareReplay operator (and learn about pipeable operators. Your way of applying operators won't work anymore with Angular 6). https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the response. Do you have an example of how I would do this with my code above? When I was looking at pipes from the angular demo (they used it for logging) I wasn't able to change the returned data. I was able to toss on `.pipe(shareReplay(1))` at the end. And it does work, but are you referring to how I was using `flatMap`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. It should be `this.httpClient.get<...>(...).pipe(flatMap(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the recommendation of @JB Nizet in the comments above I refactored my call to this:

```
call(): Observable<...>{
    return service.observable = service.observable || this.httpClient.get<...>(...)
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                ...
                return ...;
            }),
            shareReplay(1)
        );
}
```